# RegEx - get expression and next 3 lines

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-3.0

I am using Powershell to try and parse a file.  I need to get an expression, and then the next 3 lines.  The expression part works. The 3 line part doesn't. I'm not sure how to do this.

```
$regex = ‘(TOTALS).*?(ACCT TYPE CODE:).*?(\d)(\d)(\d).*?\r.*?\r.*?\r’
```

Thanks

Comment: I tried \n also.  When I look at the file, each line has a carriage return and line feed.

Comment: Have you tried \r\n for both carriage return and linefeed? This is the format windows uses for line feed.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. I think I need a lookback or lookforward or something.

Comment: I think the . does not match a newline character and that is part of the problem too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `select-string` with the `-context` parameter. E.g.

```
Get-content $somefile | select-string -pattern $regex -context 0,3
```

This will return `matchinfo` objects which will include the extra lines following the line with the match.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2010/05/07/select-string-context.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Get-Content to get the contents of that file. What you need to do is use Select-String -Pattern -Context

```
Select-String -Path $File -Pattern "(TOTALS).*?(ACCT TYPE CODE:).*?(\d)(\d)(\d).*?" -Context 0,2
```